# iptables rules to access/mount a remote NFS server

Tags: iptables, nfs, tcp

Actually when iptables rules are not cleared, trying to mount a remote NFS share failed with a timeout. After a reset of iptables rules, i'm allowed to mount properly the NFS remote server.

What are the iptables rules to allow access to a remote NFS server ?

I use `rw,_netdev,mountproto=tcp` as mount option.

Comment: sound like to have a default policy to block-out going connections. make sure you allow RELATED & ESTABLISHED connection in your input chain. also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187345/iptables-rules-for-nfs-server-and-nfs-client

Comment: what is " rpcinfo -p | grep nfs " output

Comment: @Babby : no NFS entry, here is the full output of [rpcinfo -p](http://paste.debian.net/776014/)

Comment: Here is the output of 'rpcinfo -p remote_addr |grep nfs' : [http://paste.debian.net/776018/](http://paste.debian.net/776018/)

Comment: @fashuai : port number 2049 is allow for INPUT and OUTPUT in iptables?

Comment: @Babyy : i don't think so, here is /etc/iptables.rules file loaded via rc.local : [http://paste.debian.net/776048/](http://paste.debian.net/776048/)

Comment: @fashuai run this command and test again your NFS http://paste.debian.net/776063/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NFSv4, the only port you'll need to allow will be 2049/TCP (or SCTP if both ends support it and you choose to use it).

So the iptables rules for the client side would be:

```
-A INPUT -s <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --sport 2049 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
```

---

If using NFSv3 or older, you will need to allow a number of additional ports:

- port 111 (`portmapper` or `rpcbind`), TCP and/or UDP.
- a port for NFS file locking service (`lockd` or `nlockmgr`), commonly 4045 but may vary
- a port for NFS status/recovery service (`rpc.statd`)
- a port for NFS mount daemon (`rpc.mountd`)

The problem with the last three is that classically those port numbers used to be dynamically assigned, and the `portmapper`/`rpcbind` service in port 111 was used to locate them. This makes setting up firewalls awkward, so modern Linux systems will allow configuring fixed port numbers for those services. **Most of these need to be configured at the NFS server side**, but the `rpc.statd` needs to be on both NFS client and server.

On Linux, the file locking service is usually handled by the `lockd` kernel module, so its port configuration takes the form of a kernel module option.
If your distribution does not already include a more specific way to configure this, you can always create a file as `/etc/modprobe.d/nfs-options.conf` and type this line into it:

```
options lockd nlm_udpport=4045 nlm_tcpport=4045
```

(At least HP-UX 11.31 and Solaris use port 4045 for NFS lockd by default, so that's another reason for standardizing on port number 4045 for it.)

Allowing `rpc.statd` with a NFSv3 or NFSv2 setup is vital if you wish your NFS mounts to handle server or client reboots gracefully. Find out how your distribution starts the daemon, and if there is no more specific way to do it, add `-p 4046` to the `rpc.statd` command line used to start the daemon to make it use a fixed port number.

`rpc.mountd` is another essential service with NFSv3 or NFSv2. It can also be configured to use a fixed port by adding `-p 4047` to the command line that starts the daemon, unless your distribution has a more specific way to configure NFS services. As you had already specified the `mountproto=tcp` mount option, there is no need to cover the UDP case.

RedHat has concentrated all NFS port settings to variables located in `/etc/sysconfig/network`. In RHEL and related distributions, you can achieve all these settings by just adding these lines to `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
LOCKD_TCPPORT=4045
LOCKD_UDPPORT=4045
STATD_PORT=4046
MOUNTD_PORT=4047
```

On Debian and its relatives, you can specify `rpc.statd` port in file `/etc/default/nfs-common` by setting the `STATDOPTS` variable:

```
STATDOPTS="-p 4046"
```

Likewise, you can configure a port number for `rpc.mountd` by setting the `RPCMOUNTDOPTS` variable in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`:

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="-p 4047"
```

After these configurations, the necessary NFS-client-side iptables rules would be:

```
-A INPUT -s <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT # incoming portmapper requests
-A INPUT -s <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --sport 2049 -j ACCEPT # incoming NFS protocol
-A INPUT -s <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 4046 -j ACCEPT # for reboot detection and file lock recovery
-A OUTPUT -d <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT # outgoing portmapper requests
-A OUTPUT -d <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT # main NFS port
-A OUTPUT -d <NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/32 -p tcp --dport 4045:4047 -j ACCEPT # lockd, statd, mountd
```

As you can see, NFSv4 is much simpler to get through firewalls than NFSv3 and older.

In practice, you will probably want to avoid NFSv2, as it has an inherent file size limit of 2 GB, which is going to be uncomfortably small for many modern uses.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add 2 lines to the `/etc/iptables.rules` file.

Just below the `ICMP` section :

```
#### NAS [IN,OUT]
-A INPUT  -i eth0 -s NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d NAS_SERVER_IP_ADDR/32 -j ACCEPT
```